# How to underline ylabel?

Tags: python, matplotlib

it's possible to underline ylabel? for example i have the label:

```
ax1.set_ylabel(u'Seconds To Process', rotation=0)
```

How to underline text of ylabel 'Seconds To Process'?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727368/underlining-text-in-python-matplotlib

Comment: i found that, but when i try use this, i got next error: `RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'lp'`

Comment: i read that the user got the same error message as you are and they seem to think that it comes from missing certain packages for Latex which I guess will depend on your OS. So you might want to search into which Latex packages there are for you OS.