# How to type lower bar in a string by python plot?

Tags: python, mathematical-expressions

I want to add some text to a python plot. I'm using **r'$\bar{p}$'**, but I want the bar to be at the bottom. I tried to use latex package accent and write **r'$\usepackage{accents} \underaccent{\bar}{p}$'**. But it doesn't work.

Any idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which package do you use for plotting?

Comment: I'm using matplotlib.pyplot. But I think this is only related to how to input mathematical expressions in a string generally, not to plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not ideal, since the `\underline` produces a slightly different line than `\underaccent`, but you could still use it the way mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727730/5829566).
To give the letter p the same font as in latex formula, you can use `\underline{$p$}`.

Here is a short example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text',usetex=True)
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(-5,5,0.1)
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x),label=r'\underline{$p$}')
ax.legend()
f.show()
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful and up to your expectations, I'd be happy if you upvoted it.

Comment: I tried. My reputation isn't enough to do that. I'll upvote it when I get the privilege.

Comment: Ah, true, sorry, I am also very new to this. But you should be able to accept my answer as valid answer to your question.